# Mongoose: Pushing values to an array inside a nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been searching for an answer for this for hours - there seem to be some similar questions without a working answer - so if you can help me solve it then you can have my car, my house and my first born - whatever you want!

When I create a record for the model below, I need a way to insert values to the participants nested array:

```
const recordSchema = new Schema (
    {record: 
        [
            {
                eventDate: Date,
            game: { 
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
                ,ref: "Game"
            },
            winner: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
                ,ref: "Member"
            },
            particpants: [
                {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
                    ,ref: "Member"
                }
            ]
            },
            {
                timestamps: true, 
            }
        ],         
    }    
)
```

Creating a record works fine for all fields except participants, which remains unpopulated:

```
Record.create({record: { game: game, winner: winner, participants: participants }})
```

I have tried several methods to try to get to that nested array and (for example) update after creation, but so far I haven't been able to get there. Keep in mind this needs to create programatically - I can't hard code in any values.

Many, many, many thanks if you are able to help me with this.

Edit: adding the data being input as comment said this would be useful:
console logging the variables right before the create returns the following: game: '6220ca4d8179d6685b4c05b7', winner: '6225ed9f21a3b31c86098b8d', participants: [ '6225ec458e34373cf7337d68', '6225ed9f21a3b31c86098b8d' ]

Comment: Can you post the data you are trying to pass when calling `.create()`? I suspect there might be an issue with the structure of the data you are passing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - console logging the variables right before the create returns the following:   
game: '6220ca4d8179d6685b4c05b7',
winner: '6225ed9f21a3b31c86098b8d',
participants: [ '6225ec458e34373cf7337d68', '6225ed9f21a3b31c86098b8d' ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your schema, as you can see your schema expects `particpants` but in your `.create()` you are passing `participants`.

You are missing an `i` after `c` in schema.

```
participants: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Member" }]
```

Comment: This worked and I am so embarassed! Thank you so much sir for finding this typo for me!

Comment: Please mark is correct, for others to find